# Moving and renaming contents of an XML node

Tags: xslt, transformation

i am a newbie when it comes to XSLT translations, and have been searching with this question for a while, but did not find any answher to it. I have an XML file looking like this:

```
<item>
  <code>I001</code>
  <description>DEF</description>
  <properties>
    <line1>
      <key>key 1</key>
      <value>value 1</value>
    </line1>
    <line2>
      <key>key 2</key>
      <value>value 2</value>
    </line2>
  </properties>
</item>
```

The label-software that i need to process this data with does not cope with this kind of leveled xml, so i have to transform it to something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<item>
  <code>I001</code>
  <description>DEF</description>
  <P1_key>key 1</P1_key>
  <P1_value>value 1</P1_value>
  <P2_key>key 1</P2_key>
  <P2_value>value</P2_value>
</item>
```

So far i have come up with an xsl-file that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <!-- Identity rule -->
  <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- special rules ... -->
  <xsl:template match="properties/line1/*">
    <xsl:element name="P1_{local-name()}">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="properties/line2/*">
    <xsl:element name="P2_{local-name()}">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This does only partly what i need (renaming the elements), wit a result looking like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<item>
  <code>I001</code>
  <description>DEF</description>
  <properties>
    <line1>
      <P1_key>key 1</P1_key>
      <P1_value>value 1</P1_value>
    </line1>
    <line2>
      <P2_key>key 1</P2_key>
      <P2_value>value</P2_value>
    </line2>
  </properties>
</item>
```

What i now would like to now is how to move the renamed elements (P1_key, P1_value, P2_key, P2_value) to the  level.

Any hints would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/item">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="code | description"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="properties/*/key">
            <xsl:element name="P{position()}_key">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="P{position()}_value">
                <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::value[1]"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Or perhaps:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/item">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="code | description"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="properties/*/key">
        <xsl:variable name="line-num" select="substring-after(name(..), 'line')" />
            <xsl:element name="P{$line-num}_key">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="P{$line-num}_value">
                <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::value[1]"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Of course, if there always will be exactly two lines, you could just spell it out:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/item">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="code | description"/>
        <P1_key>
            <xsl:value-of select="properties/line1/key" />
        </P1_key>
        <P1_value>
            <xsl:value-of select="properties/line1/value" />
        </P1_value>
        <P2_key>
            <xsl:value-of select="properties/line2/key" />
        </P2_key>
        <P2_value>
            <xsl:value-of select="properties/line2/value" />
        </P2_value>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

BTW, your method could work too, if you add another template:

```
<xsl:template match="properties | line1 | line2">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestions. As the real XML i want to transform is somewhat complexer than my example, i think i'll go with your second suggestion. In the mean time i had come up with the possibility to spell everything out, but that left me with an XSLT-file of 53kB! Thanks again!